# Error al cargar archivo excel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-basic

Buenas tardes amigos estoy intentando cargar un archivo de excel ah un gridview pero me muestra el siguiente error espero puedan ayudarme

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utilizando Visual Basic con asp.net
este es el codigo

```
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ASPxButton1.Click

    If ASPxUploadControl1.UploadedFiles.Count > 0 Then
        Dim file As UploadedFile = ASPxUploadControl1.UploadedFiles(0)
        Dim dt As New DataTable()

        ' Lee los datos del archivo de Excel en un DataTable
        Using stream As Stream = file.FileContent
            Using reader As IExcelDataReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream)
                dt.Load(reader)
            End Using
        End Using

        ' Vincula el DataTable al control ASPxGridView
        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```